# VIM: Select between ours/theirs conflict block

Tags: editor, vim

This question is on how to have useful mappings for select ours or theirs on a conflict block like

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
ours code
=======
theirs code
>>>>>>> branch
```

Comment: You need to break it up in a proper answer. See [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). I'll leave you some time to do so yourself :)

Comment: You can answer your own question and accept it too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just paste the following code into your ~/.vimrc and use `,fc`, `,so` and `,st`.
(complete .vimrc at https://github.com/brauliobo/gitconfig)

```
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
" Find Nearest
" Source: http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/find-closest-occurrence-in-both-directions-td1183340.html
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                                                        
function! FindNearest(pattern)
  let @/=a:pattern
  let b:prev = search(a:pattern, 'bncW')
  if b:prev
    let b:next = search(a:pattern, 'ncW')
    if b:next
      let b:cur = line('.')
      if b:cur - b:prev == b:next - b:cur
        " on a match
      elseif b:cur - b:prev < b:next - b:cur
        ?
      else
        /
      endif
    else
      ?
    endif
  else
    /
  endif
endfunction

command! -nargs=1 FN call FindNearest(<q-args>)
nmap \ :FN<space>

""" Select between conflict blocks
" select ours
nmap <leader>so \<<<<<<<<CR>dd/=======<CR>V/>>>>>>><CR>d
" select theirs
nmap <leader>st \<<<<<<<<CR>V/=======<CR>dk/>>>>>>><CR>dd
" find next conflict
nmap <leader>fc /<<<<<<<<CR>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have written a plugin for that: [ConflictMotions](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3991). It offers the following mappings:

```
    ]x     Go to [count] next start of a conflict.
    ]X     Go to [count] next end of a conflict.
    [x     Go to [count] previous start of a conflict.
    [X     Go to [count] previous end of a conflict.
    ]z     Go to [count] next conflict marker.
    [z     Go to [count] previous conflict marker.

    ax     "a conflict" text object, select [count] conflicts,
           including the conflict markers.
    az     "a conflict section" text object, select [count]
           sections (i.e. either ours, theirs, or base) including
           the conflict marker above, and in the case of "theirs"
           changes, also the ending conflict marker below.
    iz     "inner conflict section" text object, select current
           section (i.e. either ours, theirs, or base) without
           the surrounding conflict markers.
```